# How to establish socket connection using the command line

Tags: windows, sockets, batch-file

How can I establish my socket connection using the Windows command line?

For example, my socket IP and port num is `192.168.1.180:9760`

I just want to send commands to that IP from the command line.

Comment: Are you *actually* using DOS? Or are you using the command line interface in Windows. They're very different things, and the latter *is not* DOS.
Also, I don't believe there is any standard utility in the windows CLI (or DOS for that matter) that will do this. `telnet` is close, and will give you a quick "is the port open?" test. What you really want is `netcat` (`nc`) which is a standard tool in Unix.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use "netcat", or "nc" as it is sometimes called.

So if the server is using UDP on port 9760, you can use:

```
nc -u 192.168.1.180 9760
```

Comment: don't seem to have "netcat", or "nc" on my windows xp box

Comment: You can download it easily enough... http://nc110.sourceforge.net   See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat

Comment: Mark Setchell why did  you use a password ?

Comment: Using `Bash on Ubuntu on Windows` I excluded the `-u` switch. ;)

Answer (score 20):

You can use telnet as in

```
telnet 192.168.1.180 9760
```

Comment: You might have to install the Windows telnet client by going to Control Panel->Programs_and_Features->Turn_Windows_Features_on_or_off and select "Telnet Client" from the list of features not installed by default.

Comment: @selbie I came here in 2022 to upvote a comment made by you in 2013. Your comment solved the exact same problem I was facing.