# How to Send Commands to socket using batch file

Tags: sockets, batch-file, command-line, windows-7

I just want to send Commands(Eg.00LI002LE99) to an local IP, `192.168.1.186` `9760`, I am trying to send that command using Batch programming,

I have tried :

1.

```
@echo off
cd..
cd C:\nc
nc 192.168.1.180 9760
00LI002LE99
end
```

2.

```
 echo 00LI002LE99| nc 192.168.1.186 9760
```

I can open the socket, but i cant send that command. Please help me on this.

Comment: Why use ancient "batch" technology? PowerShell can directly call upon any .NET Framework classes, just in case it doesn't already have a built-in way to do these things.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to establish socket connection using the command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346456/how-to-establish-socket-connection-using-the-command-line)

Answer (score 1):

Try this: add an `exit` command at end, and rename the file to .txt extension:

**testfile.txt:**

```
@echo off
cd..
cd C:\nc
nc 192.168.1.180 9760
00LI002LE99
end
exit
```

Then, "execute" it this way:

```
cmd < testfile.txt
```

Comment: not working!! and Aacini how to disconnect the socket using command?

Comment: If not working, then `nc` program doesn't admit input redirection, and there is no way to solve that :-(

Answer (score 1):

```
echo 00LI002LE99| nc 192.168.1.180 9760
```